# cycle IF based on autofilter condition

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to solve a problem I'm actually stuck on due to my inexperience with Excel Macro. I'd like to build an IF cycle based on an Autofilter choice; in case of a positive feedback (**"Magnet" autofilter choice**) the macro should show some previously hidden columns.

This one is my actual macro, but I've a problem on the first `if` statement

```
Sub Hide()
    If ActiveSheet.Range("$B$8:$V$20").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Magnet" Then
        Range("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic:**

1. Check if the worksheet has Autofilter
2. Check if the filter is on in the relevant field
3. Retrieve the criteria and then if it matches your requirement, show/hide the columns

Try this

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim af As AutoFilter

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Check if there is an Autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then

            '~~> Set your autofilter object
            Set af = .AutoFilter

            '~~> Check if the 6th field is filtered
            If af.Filters(6).On Then
                '~~> Check if the criteria matches.
                If af.Filters(6).Criteria1 = "=Magnet" Then
                    .Range("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                Else
                    .Range("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreensHot**

[image]